# Unknown compiler option 'angularCompilerOptions' in angular 2 ahead-of-time compilation

Tags: angular, angular2-cli, angular2-compiler

I'm trying to use [AOT](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) compiler in [this](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) angular 2 project. I get error: `TypeError: this.compiler.compileModules` is not a function when I execute command: `"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json` . 
How to solve this issue?

Steps to reproduce:

1. clone this repo: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter
2. install compiler-cli (version 2.1.2): npm install @angular/compiler-cli --save
3. remove `src/app/+detail` directory and `detail` router from `src/app/app.routes.ts` (I did it because `"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json` outputs error: `can't resolve module src/app/+detail/index.ts from src/app/+detail/index.ts`)
4. create `tsconfig-aot.json`:

   {
       "compilerOptions": {
           "target": "es5",
           "module": "es2015",
           "moduleResolution": "node",
           "sourceMap": true,
           "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
           "experimentalDecorators": true,
           "removeComments": false,
           "noImplicitAny": true,
           "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
       },
       "angularCompilerOptions": {
           "genDir": "aot",
           "skipMetadataEmit" : true
       }
   }
5. run `"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue and resolved it by making sure the "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1" and "@angular/compiler-cli" are using the same version number.  e.g. "@angular/compiler-cli" should be "2.1.1" to match the compiler version.

Comment: yes, the same issue and same solution, it seems @angular/compiler and @angular/compiler-cli shoud strictly be the same version,  in my case 2.1.2

Comment: And what to do if the same issue is  producing in angular@4